# Reference table and match date public holiday

Tags: excel

I have a table that looks like this (named range *PubHols*):

```
Holiday               2018          2019        2020       2021

New Year's Day      01/01/2018  01/01/2019  01/01/2020  01/01/2021

Australia Day       26/01/2018  28/01/2019  27/01/2020  26/01/2021

Good Friday         30/03/2018  19/04/2019  10/04/2020  02/04/2021

Holy Saturday       31/03/2018  20/04/2019  11/04/2020  03/04/2021

Easter Sunday       01/04/2018  21/04/2019  12/04/2020  04/04/2021

Easter Monday       02/04/2018  22/04/2019  13/04/2020  05/04/2021

ANZAC Day           25/04/2018  25/04/2019  25/04/2020  25/04/2021

Queen's Birthday    11/06/2018  10/06/2019  08/06/2020  14/06/2021

Labour Day          01/10/2018  07/10/2019  05/10/2020  04/10/2021

Christmas Day       25/12/2018  25/12/2019  25/12/2020  25/12/2021

Boxing Day          26/12/2018  26/12/2019  26/12/2020  26/12/2021
```

Trying to incorporate into a function - that is to check if the date is a public holiday first, and then run the ifs.

- Current formula is:
  `=IF($A2="","",IFS(WEEKDAY($A2)=1,"Sun",WEEKDAY($A2)=2,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=3,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=4,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=5,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=6,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=7,"Saturday"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the test for a public holiday into your existing formula like this:

```
=IFS($A$2="","",COUNTIF(PubHols,A2),"Public Holiday",WEEKDAY($A2)=1,"Sun",WEEKDAY($A2)=2,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=3,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=4,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=5,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=6,"Weekday",WEEKDAY($A2)=7,"Saturday")
```

But there are much shorter ways of testing if a date is a working day, e.g. [the one described here](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-dates/how-to-find-if-a-day-is-a-holiday-or-weekday-in-excel.html)

```
=WORKDAY(A2-1,1,PubHols)=A2
```

So if you wanted to tell if the day was a working day, public holiday, Saturday or Sunday you could use:

```
=IFS(A2="","",WORKDAY(A2-1,1,PubHols)=A2,"Working Day",WEEKDAY(A2)=1,"Sun",WEEKDAY(A2)=7,"Sat",TRUE,"Public holiday")
```

[image]

It's interesting that the two formulas give different results. I think the reason is that a public holiday should never fall on a weekend, so probably Monday 28th December will be a public holiday this year rather than Saturday 26th.